# Deserialisation with two possible property names for a property in json.net?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have two "keys" for each json property. I always serialize with the short property name but for deserialization I need to support both short and long property name.
So in example below I need support "cid" and "customIdentifier" when deserializing to SimpleClass. No risk for conflicts, just need support to handle two property names.

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    [JsonProperty("cid")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DeserializationDemo
{
    [TestCase("{\"cid\": 1}")]
    [TestCase("{\"customIdentifier\": 1}")]
    public void JsonConvert_Can_Deserialize(string json)
    {
        var expected = new SimpleClass() { Id = 1 };
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleClass>(json);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Id, result.Id);
    }

    [TestCase("{\"cid\":1}")]
    public void JsonConvert_Can_Serialize(string expected)
    {
        var test = new SimpleClass() { Id = 1 };
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for the testfixture - wish more questions were presented like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Json.NET will deserialize a private and/or set-only property when marked with [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).  Thus you can do:

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    [JsonProperty("cid")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customIdentifier")]
    int CustomIdentifier
    {
        set
        {
            Id = value;
        }
    }
}
```